# Online visualization tool for planes (spans in linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software

I would like to visualize planes in 3D as I start learning linear algebra, to build a solid foundation. Surprisingly, I have been unable to find an online tool (website/web app) to visualize planes in 3 dimensions. For example, I'd like to be able to enter 3 points and see the plane.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Try [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2x%2B3y-5z%3D7).

Comment: You will gain greater insight if you learn to plot and visualize them with a pencil. You can usually get your points by plotting the $x$, $y$ and $z$ intercepts. If three intercepts don't exist you can still plug in and graph other points.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A great site is [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/3d). It starts in 2D by default, but you can click on a settings button on the right to open a 3D viewer. You can add a point anywhere on the page then double-click it to set its coördinates. There are many tools, including drawing the plane determined by three given points. One of the pleasures of this site is that you can drag any of the points and it will dynamically adjust the objects you have created (so dragging a point will move the corresponding plane).

Here is a screenshot of the plane through $(3,0,0),(0,2,0)$, and $(0,0,4)$:

$\hskip2cm$[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should checkout [CPM_3D_Plotter](https://technology.cpm.org/general/3dgraph/).
It runs in the browser, therefore you don't have to download or install any programs.
Because it is browser-based, it is also platform independent.
The user-interface is very clean and simple to use:

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2):

Relaxing the online restriction, I quite like [Grapher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) (for macOS). For example, here is a plot of two planes, the plane in Théophile's answer and the plane $z = 0$, and of the three given points:

[image]